# how to output correct html with json using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, json

Hi I would like to output the code in `[json['information']` as actual converted html code.

At the moment it seems to be just outputting the entire string as pure text (unformatted html, so you can see all the tags etc)
Im still learning about `json` so am unsure what is supposed to be done with the content recieved to make it proper html.

Thanks in advance

```
$('.engineering-services').live('click', function() {     
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=information/information/homepage_info',
    type: 'post',
    data: {info_for : 'engineering'},
    dataType: 'json',
    success:    function(json){

    $('#engineering-content').html(json['information']);
    },
    error: function(json) {
    alert('fail');
    }
    });
   });
```

EDIT, heres the PHP ...

```
    public function homepage_info() {
    $this->load->model('catalog/information');
    $json = array();
    if (isset($this->request->post['info_for'])) {
        if ($this->request->post['info_for'] == 'engineering') {    
            $information_info = $this->model_catalog_information->getInformation(10);
            $json['information'] = $information_info['description'];                
            }
            $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
            }

            }
```

Comment: You're probably encoding stuff like `<` as `&lt;` on the server side, when generating the JSON (using `htmlspecialchars`, maybe?). Can we see the JSON, or part of it?

Comment: Ive edited to include the php, sorry if this is a stupid question, but what do you mean by the JSON part? As in the actual output?

Comment: also, I think you're right about &lt etc, but is there a way around this?

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the JSON output. But try this: `$this->response->setOutput(json_encode(html_entity_decode($json)));`. Looks like the data is already encoded on your model/database.

Comment: Actually: `$json['information'] = html_entity_decode ($information_info['description']);`

Comment: Thank you bfavaretto, that worked a charm, feel free to answer it and ill mark it as correct. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML strings seem to be encoding special characters as HTML entities, like `<` to `&lt;`, etc. From the PHP you've shown, it's probably encoded in the database (maybe you're encoding before saving).

You should be able to fix it with [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

```php
$json['information'] = html_entity_decode($information_info['description']);
// or, a few lines later:
// $this->response->setOutput(html_entity_decode(json_encode($json)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Open cart for you php controller. In order to send back a a response with the proper json headers the Open Cart way is as follows:

```
$this->load->library('json');
$this->response->setOutput(Json::encode($json));
```

Hope that helps.